# Multiple Queries; No Return at all when One Query's Results are Null

Tags: mysql, excel, date, google-apps-marketplace

I am using two `query` and `ImportRange` functions to combine and sort data from two Google spreadsheets. The query is intended to select data from these sheets when Col2 falls within a specified date range.

One of the spreadsheets being imported will ALWAYS have information that falls within the date range; however, the second sheet occasionally does not. When this happens, the query returns nothing at all — not even the values related to the first sheet. I get this error message:

> In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Does anyone know of a way to "forgive" the second sheet for not having any pertinent values and allow the query to still run for the first sheet?

My formula:

```
=sort({
    query(ImportRange("1OgIJX99mHPCnyyKqIX3tHP2RsFLT7FGO-63qaGlcqCQ","Master!$A$3:$L"),"select Col2, Col4, Col12 where Col8 != 'School' and Col1 != 'Cancelled' and Col2<=date """&text(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and Col2>=date """&text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ");
    query(ImportRange("155fTvvw6hE6ZA6e_rysL2UR-5UMAjyaLVDMawpjTnpg","Master!$A$3:$L"),"select Col2, Col3, Col10 where Col1 != 'Cancelled' and Col2<=date """&text(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and Col2>=date """&text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ")
})
```

Comment: You may want to add the conditions suggested in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dI3_vwDO060) like using "Select * where Col1 is not null" or to merge the arrays before filtering them as mentioned [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jEOxuABEGfQ).

Comment: Thanks, @Teyam. I ended up querying and importing the two sheets into a new tab, without using any date criteria. Then, I ran a query on the new combined data set based on date.